# Jest Enzyme Cannot spy the property because it is not a function; undefined given instead when spyOn testing a function in component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, enzyme, spyon

I am testing on the execution of functions inside a React component that's connected to redux store.
I was only able to spy on some of the functions, the rest all returned:
Cannot spy the setEmail(or other function names) property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

below in code I added arrows pointing out which ones are spy-able, when I console.log(BaseForm.WrappedComponent.prototype.functionName) the ones that are not spy-able returned undefined. the one that can be spied on returned [Function:...]
I really do not understand why?

```
class BaseForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ages: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createAges(); <----- can spy on this one as it is a function
  }

  setEmail = (elemName, value) => { <------ Cannot spy the setEmail property because it is not a function; undefined
    this.setState({ email: value });
    this.props.saveEmail(value);
  };

  handleEmailSignup = (e) => { <-------- Cannot spy the setEmail property because it is not a function; undefined
    this.setState({ offersSignup: e.target.checked });
  };

  onChangeAge = (e) => { <------ Cannot spy the setEmail property because it is not a function; undefined
    this.setState({
      selectedAge: e.target.value,
      selectedAgeIndex: e.target.index - 1,
      errorAge: '',
    });
  };

  createAges() { <------ can spyOn as it is a function
    let ages = [
      { value: '', text: !__isEmpty(sessionStorage.getItem('gf')) ? 'Kid age' : 'Your age' },
      { value: '14 and younger', text: '14 and younger' },
      { value: '15', text: '15' },
      { value: '16', text: '16' },
      { value: '17', text: '17' },
    ];

    this.setState({ ages: ages });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div data-type="email" className="textbox-wrapper">
          <Textbox
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            name="register-email"
            onChange={this.setEmail}
            onBlur={this.checkUserByEmail}
            defaultValue={this.state.email} <------- in test the value does not change, but on UI it does and functions well
            isError={!__isEmpty(this.props.emailErrorClass)}
          />
        </div>

        <Dropdown options={this.state.ages} onChange={this.onChangeAge} selectedValue={this.state.selectedAge} />

        <div>
          <input name="offersSignup" type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleEmailSignup} checked={this.state.offersSignup} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { saveEmail };

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BaseForm);
```

```
it.only('set email in local state if onChange of Textbox is fired', () => {
    //console.log(BasePartnerRegistrationForm.WrappedComponent.prototype.setEmail);
    // above is undefined
    const setEmailSpy = jest.spyOn(BaseForm.WrappedComponent.prototype, 'setEmail');
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BaseForm {...baseProps} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const event = { target: { value: 'event value' } };
    wrapper.find('Textbox').at(0).simulate('change', event);
    wrapper.update();
    expect(setEmailSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // below shows unchanged email value in state
    // expect(wrapper.find('Textbox').at(0).props().defaultValue).toBe(event.target.value);
  });
```

Below tried a new approach, console errors:
Expected: "event value"
Received: ""
in other words,per test case, the setState is not functioning, but it functions well on UI and in chrome console too.

```
it('set email in local state if onChange of Textbox is fired', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BasePartnerRegistrationForm {...baseProps} />
      </Provider>
    );

    const event = { target: { value: 'event value' } };
    wrapper.find('Textbox').at(0).simulate('change', event);
    await waitFor(() => expect(wrapper.find('Textbox').at(0).props().defaultValue).toBe(event.target.value));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spying on the method call, just check the DOM. First, I would suggest you look at [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) for finding fields, setting values, querying the DOM for changes. This, with Jest, is the new standard in React testing (even included with React-Create-App). It's a paradigm shift, in that use test user interaction and result (as a user would), which is testing the underlying logic.

The next thing to consider is timing. When you set state it isn't immediate. It takes a few milliseconds for state changes to render. RTL provides a `waitFor` method that simplifies this further.

```js
waitFor(() => /*some assertion*/);
```

Comment: Hi thank you! I added the last code block per your suggestion in the question, it is not returning the updated value(new value thats set in state). the component and UI functions correctly tho.